# SQL : select top 4 results with the higher votes UP and lower votes DOWN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have like to do sthg simple, but I have no idea where to start.

so I have 4 tables :

> - Table question   (id_question)
> - Table trad       (id_trad, #id_question)
> - Table vote_up    (id_vote_up, #id_trad)
> - Table vote_down  (id_vote_down, #id_trad)

for the id_question=1, I would like to select the 4 translations (from trad) with the higher number of vote_up and with the lower number of vote_down

is it possible to do that with a single query? Any idea?

or maybe it's better to simply add "upvotes" and "downvotes" and update the corresponding field by 1 ?

Comment: do you mean that you want 8 records : with the 4 highest upvotes followed/appended by the 4 lowest downvotes ?

Comment: Join + Union + Limit

Comment: @amdixon no indeed I would like just 4, each upvote give 1 point and each downvote lose 1 point, and I would like the top 4 with the higher points

Comment: @VR46 yes thank you, but I'm not an expert in sql

Comment: i suggest restructuring your votes into one table

Comment: normally, there should be single total rating which depends on upvotes and downvotes simultaneously. Like on SO site.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thank you but let's say you want to ban a contributor, how to delete his votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**plan**

> - get count of upvotes grouped by each trad
> - get count of downvotes grouped by each trad
> - left join all trad to above datasources with score function, order by and limit of 4

---

**example input**

```
create table question
(
  id_question integer primary key not null
  -- other metadata here..
);

create table trad
(
  id_trad integer primary key not null,
  id_question integer not null,
  foreign key ( id_question ) references question ( id_question )
);

create table vote_up
(
  id_vote_up integer primary key not null,
  id_trad integer not null,
  foreign key ( id_trad ) references trad ( id_trad )
);

create table vote_down
(
  id_vote_down integer primary key not null,
  id_trad integer not null,
  foreign key ( id_trad ) references trad ( id_trad )
);

insert into question
( id_question )
values
( 1 )
;

insert into trad
( id_trad, id_question )
values
( 1, 1 ),
( 2, 1 ),
( 3, 1 ),
( 4, 1 ),
( 5, 1 ),
( 6, 1 ),
( 7, 1 )
;

insert into vote_up
( id_vote_up, id_trad )
values
( 1, 1 ),
( 2, 1 ),
( 3, 1 ),
( 4, 1 ),
( 5, 1 ),
( 6, 1 ),
( 7, 3 ),
( 8, 3 ),
( 9, 3 ),
( 10, 3 ),
( 11, 4 ),
( 12, 4 ),
( 13, 5 ),
( 14, 6 ),
( 15, 6 ),
( 16, 7 ),
( 17, 7 ),
( 18, 7 )
;

insert into vote_down
( id_vote_down, id_trad )
values
( 1, 1 ),
( 2, 1 ),
( 3, 1 ),
( 4, 1 ),
( 5, 1 ),
( 6, 1 ),
( 7, 3 ),
( 8, 3 ),
( 9, 3 ),
( 10, 4 ),
( 11, 4 )
;
```

---

**query**

```
select trad.id_trad, coalesce(upvotes, 0) - coalesce(downvotes, 0) as score
from trad
left join
(
select 
trad.id_trad, count(*) as upvotes
from trad
inner join vote_up
on trad.id_trad = vote_up.id_trad
group by 1
) uv
on trad.id_trad = uv.id_trad
left join
(
select 
trad.id_trad, count(*) as downvotes
from trad
inner join vote_down
on trad.id_trad = vote_down.id_trad
group by 1
) dv
on uv.id_trad = dv.id_trad
where trad.id_question = 1
order by score desc
limit 4
;
```

**output**

```
+---------+-------+
| id_trad | score |
+---------+-------+
|       7 |     3 |
|       6 |     2 |
|       3 |     1 |
|       5 |     1 |
+---------+-------+
```

**[sqlfiddle ( separate structures )](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/964091/4)**

---

**note**

> consider also restructuring your votes into one table. atm vote_up and
>   vote_down are unnecessarily duplicating the same structure..
>   this would look like :

**[sqlfiddle ( reuse structure )](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0c9270/2)**

Comment: thank you very much amdixon! yes I'll restructure to make a single vote table

Comment: no worries - added also fiddle using a combined votes table

Comment: perfect, thank you amdixon, I'll mark your answer as best answer

Comment: where id_question = $id_question  before order by was missing

Answer (score 0):

To get the first four translation with higher upvotes; join the tables using the keys, then order in ascending order of the up_votes, and in descending order their down_votes, then get the first four tranlations by doing a having ROWNUM <= 4.

Comment: I will finally take the solution of amdixon, thanks anyway!